# how to know which interface is implemented where there is multiple interface with same method signature in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface

In this code, there are 2 interface, both have same method signature, how can i know class cat has implemented which interface makesound() method? does it has implemented animal2 method or animal1
By OOPs common concepts we can say Animal2 will be implemented, but i want the data by program statement

```
// Interface definition
interface Animal1 {
  public function makeSound();
}

interface Animal2 {
    public function makeSound();
  }

// Class definitions

class Cat implements Animal1,Animal2 {
  public function makeSound() {
    echo " Meow ";
  }

}
//object n call method
$cat = new Cat();
$cat->makeSound();

?>
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, you seem to have posted your answer within the question area? If the `I got`... onwards part of your post is supposed to be solution, please post it correctly in the Answers section below. And please take the [tour] and maybe read [ask] and [answer] so you understand the format of Stackoverflow and how it works. Thanks.

Comment: that was the methods i tried but none of them worked the way i wanted

Comment: Ah ok, well in that case it's fine to include them in your question...but then you need to explain in what way it didn't provide what you wanted, and also make clear what exact result you _did_ expect.

Comment: BTW I'd argue that if two interfaces provide identical method signatures and a class implements both interfaces, then it's clear that the class has fulfilled both interface definitions, and therefore has implemented both of them. It's not clear what you are trying to ask, entirely.

Comment: Yes, both interfaces are implemented and thus both `makeSound()` methods in those interfaces, not just one or the other. You do realize that none of this matters? Whether one or the other, or both, methods are implemented, the result will be exactly the same.

Comment: Yes I do understand, what my requirement is that to get which interface method was implemented, here method overriding has been done ,where only 1 method was implemented, at server side it was combined as one , but at any instance , we can get either animal1 makesound() was choosen to implement, or animal2() makesound(). Any get_class_implemented or any method which serves these details

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You probably confuse interfaces with inheritance, in your code no method is overriden, interfaces are kind of a format, a checklist of methods that need to be implemented, they don't define a default code for them. If you omit `makeSound` in Cat, it will simply throw an error

Comment: `here method overriding has been done`...no, it hasn't, because interfaces don't have any such concept.  `we can get either animal1 makesound() was choosen to implement, or animal2() makesound()`...it's irrelevant, since the definitions of that function in each interface are identical, and nothing is removed or overridden due to the class implementing both interfaces (because interfaces don't define a concrete implementation). By implication, if it implements one of them then it implements them both, automatically.